# While, limitar o resultado

Tags: php

Gostaria de  limitar o resultado do while. 
O meu código exibe o numero de dias entre duas datas corretamente, mas gostaria de que o resultado  (no while) fosse mostrando as datas de 30 em 30 dias, como que cada linha fosse um mês, para facilitar a contagem.

Ex:

> 01-01-2017, 02-01-2017, ... completou 30 dias enter
>   01-01-2017, 02-01-2017, ... completou 30 dias enter
>   01-01-2017, 02-01-2017, ... completou 30 dias enter

Segue o meu código

```
<?php
include "exibe_ico.php";
if (empty($_POST['data_inicial']) or empty($_POST['data_final']) ) { echo "<script> window.alert('Preencha a data!'); history.back(); </script>"; exit(); }

ValidaData($_POST['data_inicial']);
ValidaData($_POST['data_final']);

$data_inicial = $_POST['data_inicial'];
$data_final = $_POST['data_final'];

function geraTimestamp($data) {
$partes = explode('/', $data);
return mktime(0, 0, 0, $partes[1], $partes[0], $partes[2]);
}

$time_inicial = geraTimestamp($data_inicial);
$time_final = geraTimestamp($data_final);

$diferenca = $time_final - $time_inicial; // 19522800 segundos
$dias = ((int)floor( $diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24))+1); // 225 dias

echo "<table border='1' width=80%>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Início</th>";
echo "<th>Fim</th>";
echo "<th>Nº dias</th>";
echo "</tr>";


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='center'>$data_inicial</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>$data_final</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>$dias</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

echo "<p><div align=left><a href='dias.php?acao=entrar'><< Voltar</a></font></div>";

?>

<?php
$Dias = 0;
$contagem = 1;
$enter = 1;
$result = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data_inicial)));
while($Dias < $dias)
{
echo "
<table>
<tr>
<td width=60 align='center'>{$contagem}º dia</td>
<td width=100 align='center'>"; echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+ $Dias days",strtotime($result))); echo "</td>
</tr>
</table>
";
$Dias++;
$contagem++;

}
```

Comment: Faça uma pergunta corretamente, informe como está o formato da data no banco, e no exemplo todas as 3 linhas estão iguais, vc gostaria de uma resposta com a mesma moeda da sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta pegar o mês do timestamp

```
$php_date = getdate($timestamp);
$mes = date("m", $timestamp);
```

Assim em cada mudança do mês você cria a quebra de linha.

Comment: Não entendi, colega!
Não estou conseguindo fazer uma quebra de linha no while (acrescentar um enter quando ele mostrar 30 itens, pode ser sem tabela.

<td width=100 align='center'>"; echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+ $Dias days",strtotime($result))); echo "</td>

Comment: Se sempre dê 30 linhas você pode fazer um contador e pegar os múltiplos de 30. Mas se existir um mês com número de registros diferente de 30 não vai funcionar, então você tem que pegar o mês corrente para saber o momento da quebra de linha, ou o seu problema é apenas no layout? De como fazer uma quebra de linha?

Comment: Vou especificar melhor, 
É informado um período, exemplo: 01/01/2017 a 01/08/2017 e o site diz quantos dias foram contados , no caso acima foram 213 dias, incluindo o 1º dia, tudo bem até aqui.
Agora no resultado é mostrado esses dias: 
1º dia: 01/01/2017

Comment: É informado um período, exemplo: 01/01/2017 a 01/08/2017 e o site diz quantos dias foram contados , no caso acima foram 213 dias, incluindo o 1º dia
Agora no resultado é mostrado esses dias: 
1º dia: 01/01/2017
2º dia: 03/01/2017 e assim por diante
Só que eu quero que ele seja mostrado assim: Layalt

01/01/2017, 02/01/2017, 03/01/2017 ... até somar 30 datas, e um Enter
xx/xx/xxxx,  xx/xx/xxxx, xx/xx/xxxx, ... até somar 30 datas, e um Ente

ou seja eu quero que essas data fiquem em linha de 30, não importa o mês ou dia, é numero de 30, não importando o início, nem fim da data

Comment: Faz assim:
if(($contador % 30) == 0){
       //Faz a quebra de linha
}

Comment: Não consegui.

<?php
$Dias = 0;
$contagem = 1;
$enter = 1;
$contador  = 1;
$result = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data_inicial)));
//ValidaData($result);
while($Dias < $dias)
{
if(($contador % 30) == 1)
{
echo "

<table>
<tr>
<td width=100 align='center'>"; echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+ $Dias days",strtotime($result))); echo "</td>
</tr>
</table>
";
}
$Dias++;
$contagem++;

}

Comment: Você tem que colocar  debaixo de ... </table>"; o if e a ação de quebra de linha, como por exemplo if(($contador % 30) == 0){ echo "<br><br>"; }, que assim toda vez que da 30 itens ele vai quebrar a linha.

Comment: Assim if(($contador % 30) == 30){ echo "<br>";} não deu certo

Coloquei assim if(($contador % 30) == 30){ echo "<br>";}
Quebrou, mas somente uma vez

Comment: Digo
Assim if(($contador % 30) == 0){ echo "<br>";} não deu certo Coloquei assim if(($contador % 30) == 10){ echo "<br>";} Quebrou, mas somente uma vez 

Como funciona % 30

Comment: Ele pega o resto da divisão, então todo múltiplo de 30 ele quebra a linha.

Comment: Ok, irmão deu certo agora. 
Agradeço

Comment: Marque como a resposta da pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Como faço para marcara como resposta

Comment: É um "V" que tem por baixo do "contador" da resposta